# UITextField leftView not triggering delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm using a subclass of `UITextField` in my `TableViewCell`. The delegate is set and whenever I tap the textfield, the delegate is called accordingly.

However, I've set the textfield's `leftViewMode` to `.always`. And when I tap on this `leftView`, nothing happens.

The `leftView` is a customized magnifier so I've added:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

or

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

    let relativeFrame = bounds
    let hitTestInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -5, left: -5, bottom: -5, right: -5)

    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(relativeFrame, hitTestInsets).contains(point)
}
```

But nothing is working when tapping the `leftView`. If possible I'd like to keep the magnifier a plain `UIView` and not adding extra gestures.